# How do I stop Selenium from closing the driver during execution?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to learn Selenium to scrape some Javascript heavy websites. I can locate and extract information just fine. However, I find that for some sites I need to switch my user agent. I did it the following way to test it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent 


PATH ="C:/my/path/to/chromedriver.exe"

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent")
```

The code works and my user agent is switched, however there is one bug that occurs now which did not occur before. The webdriver/browser (Chrome driver) automatically closes after displaying the website for a second without me specifying the `driver.quit()` argument. When I do not switch my user agent it does not close unless I do and I want to study the page a bit before closing it. I have tried to wait using `time.sleep()` but this doesn't work.

How can I make the webdriver not close until specified?

Answers are greatly appreciated, preferably with a code example of how to implement the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible that the problem is related to the webdriver version you are using or not but when I tried to add `time.sleep(n)` to your code while using `webdriver_manager` library to download most recent version of `ChromeWebDriver` I had the chance to look at the website and the browser didn't close until the timer finished.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# PATH ="C:/my/path/to/chromedriver.exe"

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent")
time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Now it worked, but if I want to perform multiple actions it becomes tiresome. Thx :)

Comment: Cool! I recommend you to use `input("continue?")` instead of `time.sleep(n)` and when you are done with one page you can press enter in terminal and it will skip it. Also, if the answer is correct, could you please accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that worked better. I have accepted your answer now ;)

Answer (score 6):

This should do you nicely:

```py
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

in your code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent 


PATH ="C:/my/path/to/chromedriver.exe"

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent")
```